# Crashing Adobe Premiere CC Pro when importing H264 MP4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, adobe, adobe-premiere

I am screencasting with kazam in Ubuntu which is h264.

To edit the video i tried to use vegas pro latest version. It only play the audio without any video.

Then i tried to edit it with adobe premier 2017. Whenever i import the file(mp4) the premier pro just crash without any useful message.

I installed quicktime for the codecs but no luck. I also converted the media with Format Factory(http://www.pcfreetime.com/) to MOV ... but premier just crash.

How can i solve this ?

here is the MediaInfo:

```
        General
    Complete name                            : C:\Users\user\Desktop\vdo.mp4
    Format                                   : MPEG-4
    Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
    Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp42/mp41/isom/iso2)
    File size                                : 23.0 MiB
    Duration                                 : 9 min 20 s
    Overall bit rate                         : 344 kb/s
    Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-02-11 06:43:57
    Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-02-11 06:43:57

    Video
    ID                                       : 1
    Format                                   : AVC
    Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
    Format profile                           : High 4:4:4 Predictive@L4
    Format settings, CABAC                   : No
    Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
    Codec ID                                 : avc1
    Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
    Duration                                 : 9 min 20 s
    Bit rate                                 : 343 kb/s
    Maximum bit rate                         : 2 097 kb/s
    Width                                    : 1 674 pixels
    Height                                   : 858 pixels
    Display aspect ratio                     : 1.951
    Frame rate mode                          : Constant
    Frame rate                               : 15.000 FPS
    Color space                              : YUV
    Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
    Bit depth                                : 8 bits
    Scan type                                : Progressive
    Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.016
    Stream size                              : 22.9 MiB (100%)
    Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2643 5c65704
    Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=6 / threads=4 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=150 / keyint_min=15 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=cqp / mbtree=0 / qp=15 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0
    Language                                 : English
    Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-02-11 06:43:57
    Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-02-11 06:43:57
```

Here is the screencast preference:
[image: In few format the kazam can record]

Comment: Show the properties of the file. Use [Mediainfo](http://www.mediaarea.net) in text mode.

Comment: Please check... I have added the information!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've recorded the video as H.264 with full chroma sampling. Most commercial editors do not work with this format. You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) to convert to the common YUV 4:2:0 sampling scheme.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy out.mp4
```

For future use, check if Kazam offers direct recording to 4:2:0.

Comment: I don't understand much about ffmpeg . But running this command worked flawlessly. I heard that ffmpeg also can record screen. I don't know the command to record a area using ffmpeg . I think kazam can't record YUV 4:2:0. I updated my post with the kazam screenshot.

Comment: ffmpeg can screencapture. On linux, you can use [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) or [video4linux](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2).

Comment: Don't use linux, so can't give the entire command but make sure that `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is present. See the docs for examples.

Comment: @rpo See [FFmpeg Wiki: Capture Desktop](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) and [FFmpeg Documentation: x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) for recording the screen.